# Making inner object in observableArray an observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Let's say I have an `observableArray` in my viewModel called `movies` that contains data similar to this...

```
[{
    Id: 12345,
    Title: 'Movie1',
    Year: 2010,,
    UserMovies: [{
        Id: 8
        IsWatched: false,
        Rating: 3.5,
        UserId: 'e1e9c075-1ded-4e7d-8d30-d5d1fbd47103'
    }]
},{
    Id: 12345,
    Title: 'Movie2',
    Year: 2010,,
    UserMovies: [{
        Id: 11
        IsWatched: false,
        Rating: 4,
        UserId: 'e1e9c075-1ded-4e7d-8d30-d5d1fbd47103'
    }]
}]
```

I know I can use the mapping plugin and every property will become an `observable` but what if I only want to make one property observable. Is it possible to make just `UserMovies` an `observableArray`, and how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify properties in your objects that you want the ko.mapping plugin to map as plain values like so:

```
var mapping = {
    'copy': ["propertyToCopy"]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

You will need to do this for each model you have defined. It can be quite tedious and depending on the nature of your model, might very well defeat the major benefit of the plugin in the first place (not having to redefine your data model client-side).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to loop each item in your array, store the `UserMovies` in a temp variable, override `UserMovies` with an observable array. Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < movies().length; i++) {
        var tempUserMovies = movies()[i].UserMovies;
        movies()[i].UserMovies = ko.observableArray();
        for (var j = 0; j< tempUserMovies.length; j++) {
            movies()[i].UserMovies.push(tempUserMovies[j]);
        }
    }
```

A little ugly method, but you should get the general idea from it.